# Terminal input does not start new line

Tags: shell, terminal

I have a random problem which I personally find quite irritating. I use the terminal alot and have installed a theme and even toyed around with what is displayed on the prompt. However if I write a particularly line of text it does not start a new line in the terminal instead it will begin overwriting what is displayed on the screen in the current terminal line. I wondered if anyone knew a way to solve this so that it does show a new line and all input would be visible.

PS1 value

```
export PS1="\r\n\e[1;32mdave:\w $\e[0;37m "
```

Comment: What is the value of your customize `PS1` variable?

Comment: export PS1="\r\n\e[1;32mdave:\w $\e[0;37m "

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, thanks to the post by @Joni, I believe the solution is:

```
PS1="\r\n\[\e[1;32m\]dave:\w $\[\e[0;37m\] "
```

That is, here the color codes `\e[1;32m` and `\e[0;37m` are enclosed within `\[` and `\]`, as @Joni suggested they should be.

Comment: An error I make all the time when modifying my prompt. Thanks!

Comment: awesome sir! :D

Answer (score 4):

Non printing characters, like escape codes for color, have to be surrounded with \[ and \] so that bash knows to exclude them when calculating the length of the line.

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/nonprintingchars.html